# PHP changes in syntax in recent versions

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm learning PHP & MYSQL using a couple of courses on Lynda.com but I notice some of the courses are older dating back to 2007. I hear PHP syntax changes a little with newer versions. Is it unwise therefore to learn from older material like this and if so what are the major differences in syntax that I need to look out for as a lot of stuff I see on the web seems up to 10 years old.

I mean, do I literally have to make sure that the course I am doing is of the latest version of PHP?

Comment: PHP syntax hasn't changed.  I wouldn't worry about it.  Just make sure your tutorials are teaching you object-oriented patterns.  You can look up the newer namespacing features yourself later.

Comment: My intuition says: "it's probably fine". Some really obscure syntax might have become deprecated but I think they've only added new things. Overall PHP hasn't changed that much, it's not like variables don't start with `$` anymore or `class` definitions no longer work, it's all very minor stuff.

Comment: If you are learning about MySQL and PHP please use Prepared Statements with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Thanks that puts my mind at rest to a large degree - just that I heard something about a change from single to double quotes or vice versa and I got worried because when you're learning you dont now if its your mistake or the code when it doesn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the changes are upward compatible. They've added new features, but haven't removed any old syntaxes. So anything you learn from a 2007 textbook will still work fine now.

An example is arrays. Recent versions of PHP allow you to create arrays using a more compact syntax:

```
$array = [foo, bar, baz];
```

But most people continue to use the old syntax:

```
$array = array(foo, bar, baz);
```

as this allows their programs to be portable to servers that aren't running the latest version.